# Is mod closing all the close Votes by EOD?

Tags: discussion

Why today close Votes are reducing like thousands.

While in morning I saw around `121.5K` close votes.

but now I can see its slashed by half the number.

is there any error in API while viewing from my side?

[image]

Just a 5 min difference.

[image]

Comment: [Related](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1859199#1859199) ... and I don't think it's a bug

Comment: The new mods have already started work, it seems.

Comment: Now it is  70.4k

Comment: [this is why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut)

Comment: No, this is a feature, and the post a duplicate. We are limiting the queue temporarily to *just* those posts with 4 close votes already.

Comment: such mods, so new, very review...

Comment: Sometimes I see `0 questions` with close votes... But that's only temporary... :-) Just remembered...

Comment: The new mods are really good! :)

Comment: @bluefeet - The voters are even better ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are *gradually* dequeuing all review tasks from the stackoverflow's close vote review queue that have less than 4 close votes as [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223349/156631).