# How is the close queue being emptied so quickly

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, flag-queue

Recently (perhaps even yesterday) the close queue was something like 130K. This morning it's *dramatically* smaller—just over 28K at the moment, and still falling fast.

How have 100K items been resolved so quickly? Does this have something to do with the recent moderator election?

Comment: We are limiting the view on the close queue to *just* the easy pickings (4 close votes), before re-introducing more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you, that makes sense. For what it's worth I really like this approach. If you add your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it, or of course the question can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Is mod closing all the close Votes by EOD? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223363/174328