# Close votes number

Tags: discussion

What happened today (February 27th 2014)?
There were 25K close votes and all of a sudden the number dropped to 14.7K.
Not that I'm complaining. I'm just curious.

Comment: @bluefeet That was amazingly fast!  You won't let people _flag_ duplicates :(

Comment: same question http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223363/174328